# Flask AJAX call missing specific values in my data

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am trying to create a web application that allows the user to send specific data to the webserver and retrieve it to process it further into functions that visualizes information to the user.

However, when sending code from the webserver back to the client, some data values within the data become 'undefined'.

```
@app.route('/_create_vis_json', methods=['GET'])                                                                         
def process_vis_input():                                                                                                 
    """ This function gets the inputs of the user of the MGcV viewer. It converts it into a json with all the information
        needed for the visualisation of the genes.                                                                       
                                                                                                                         
    :return: JSON containing info of genome                                                                              
    """                                                                                                                  
    gi_codes = request.args                                                                                              
    search = GeneConverter(gi_codes)                                                                                     
    processed_dictionary = (search.create_output_json())                                                                 
    return {'result': processed_dictionary}
```

Using the Pycharm debugger, I have concluded that all data is present when the data gets send to the front-end.

```
$(function () {
    /** when a input button with name vis_button is clicked, a ajax request is send to the server containing
     * information about the settings used in the viewer. A Json object containing information about the given
     * genes is returned to be processed into a visualisation.
     */
    $('input[name="vis_button"]').bind('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
            url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_create_vis_json',
            data: {
                gi_codes: $('textarea[name="gi_codes"]').val(),
                input_type: $('select[name="input_type"]').val(),
                context_range: $('select[name="context_range"]').val(),
                map_size: $('select[name="map_size"]').val(),
                gene_orient: $('select[name="gene_orientation"]').val(),
                gene_label: $('select[name="gene_label"]').val(),
                gene_coloring: $('select[name="gene_coloring"]').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
            console.log('==========');
            console.log(data);
            console.log('-----');
            $("#result").html(buildSVG(data.result))
        }
        });
    });
});
```

Taking a look at the console log, at the inconsistent values, 1 or more of the values will be undefined. When I repeat the process, the same values go missing.

I am using Python 3.7.4 with Flask 1.1.1 and using jquery version 3.4.1

Edit 1: As indicated by Ajax1234, I have already tried to use Flask.jsonify and got the same results. I will also include a picture of the missing data.
[Screenshot of console log of the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAtZe.png)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `flask.jsonify` instead of returning a dictionary as the response for your route. `flask.jsonify` automatically sets the appropriate `Content-Type` headers for a JSON response:

```
return flask.jsonify({'result': processed_dictionary})
```

Additionally, if `processed_dictionary` is not a basic type (`int`, `float`, `str`), you need to convert it to a JSON string:

```
flask.jsonify({'result': json.dumps(processed_dictionary)})
```

Then, in your Javascript:

```
success: function (data) {
  $("#result").html(buildSVG(JSON.parse(data.result)))
}
```

Comment: My original script contained the Jsonify function of flask. I will add this piece of missing info to the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @L.Bosch What is the type of `processed_dictionary`?

Comment: Somehow, somewhere your later edit actually made it work. I will investigate later where it originally went wrong. thank you for you quick reply.

Comment: @L.Bosch Glad to help!